# After a recent update 18.04 now only emergency mode

Tags: boot, server, mount, fstab

After a recent restart on the Ubuntu 18.04 server, after a "apt upgrade" command, the server only boots to emergency mode. I've taken a look at other similar issues found on this forum, but was unable to came up with a solution. I believe it has something to do with the "/etc/fstab" file, but I can't figure out what is the problem.

Here is the output of the "blkid" command:

[image: Output of "blkid"]

The contents of my "/etc/fstab":

[image: /etc/fstab]

And the output of "fdisk -l":

[image: fdisk -l]

Can someone help, please?

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of terminal windows. Instead, copy the relevant lines and paste them as code into your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think also that the UUIDs are wrong.
You can try to do a boot repair and/or change the UUIDs manually.

I suggest you note the UUIDs on a paper first and then try to edit in GRUB menu the UUIDs to see, if the server starts normally.

Therefore press "e" key during GRUB menu and edit the UUIDs